# Draw sprites pygame

Tags: python

i need help with my code, I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly and I don't know where the error is.
i have this error: self.character = self.character
AttributeError: 'Spriteatack' object has no attribute 'character'

```
    #loadimages
fina = pygame.image.load('fina_atack.png').convert_alpha()
darkfina = pygame.image.load('darkfina_atack.png').convert_alpha()

#class
class Spriteatack(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.sprites = []
        self.character = self.character
        self.x = self.x
        self.y = self.y
        self.qtdsprites = self.qtdsprites
        self.drawpos = self.drawpos
        inix = 0
        cont = 0
        iniy = 0
        for _ in range(16):
            temp = self.character.subsurface((inix, iniy), (self.x, self.y))
            self.sprites.append(temp)
            inix += self.x
            cont += 1
            calc = self.x * 6
            if cont == 3:
                iniy += self.y
                cont = 0
            if inix > calc:
                inix = 0
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = self.drawpos

    def update(self):
        if self.index > self.qtdsprites:
            self.index = 0
        self.index += 0.25
        self.image = self.sprites[int(self.index)]

    def trade(self, character, x, y, qtdsprites, drawpos):
        self.character = character
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.qtdsprites = qtdsprites
        self.drawpos = drawpos


    
#Grupo de sprites
allhero = pygame.sprite.Group()
hero = Spriteatack()
hero = Spriteatack.trade(fina, 302, 134, 15, (300, 200))
allhero.add(hero)
```

Comment: Please read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects). It must be `hero.trade(fina, 302, 134, 15, (300, 200))`

Comment: The line ```self.character = self.character``` is the source of your error.  You are defining self.character to itself and since it doesn't exist you can't make the assignment.  Not sure what you want, but this is the issue.